# React Navigation Back Button Doesnt do anything

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Basically what the title says. I am trying to create a back button by passing the current page routeName into the navigation state and then on the detail page I retrieve the params and pass the routeName into the goBack button. But when I click the button it doesnt do anything. I checked to see if the routeName of the previous page was in the state but it still doesnt do anything.

List Screen
Here is my Button, I am passing an id from a reducer and the routeName of the currentscreen into the navigation params

```
renderList = () => {
    const { lists } = this.props;
    if(lists) {
        return (lists.data.map(el => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    key={el.id}
                    onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('PostItem', { nid: el.id, prevScreen: this.props.navigation.state.routeName})}>
                    <Text>Next Screen</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
        ))
    }
}
```

ListDetail Screen

```
class listDetail extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.loadPost('article', this.props.navigation.state.params.nid + '?include=field_image')
        }

        render() {
            const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <View>
                    <Button title="Back" onPress={() => goBack(this.props.navigation.state.params.prevScreen)} />
                    { this.renderPost() }
                </View>
            )

        }
    }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in `goBack` refers to the `key` not the `routeName`.

From the [reactnavigation goBack docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back)

> Note -- a key is not the name of the route but the unique identifier you provided when navigating to the route. See navigation key.
>   So in your example I'd try to call navigate with a key parameter

For `renderList` onPress could be

```
onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'PostItem', key: `PostItem_${el.id}`, params: { nid: el.id } })}>
```

Then in `ListDetail`

```
<Button title="Back" onPress={() => goBack(`PostItem_${this.props.navigation.state.params.nid}`)} />
```

Comment: are you using `react-navigation` ? what version ?

Comment: 4.0. Whats happening is the params becomes undefined. Which I was able to fix. But the weird thing is that it generates a back button in the header and then if I click it it goes back to the listdetail screen which is the same screen. almost like its stuck in a loop. and fix I click the actual back button that i assigned my goBack button to it doesnt do anything. So the header back button does List -> ListDetail i click it and it goes ListDetail -> ListDetail and the button disappears